# End of the proof of Burnsides $p^aq^b$ Theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> **Theorem.** Every group of order $p^aq^b$ ($p,q$ primes $a,b \geq 0$) is soluble.

Near the end of the proof of Burnsides $p^aq^b$ Theorem, we want to prove the following

> If $\rho:G \longrightarrow GL(V)$ is the irreducible representation with character $\chi$ and $z \in C$ ($C$ cong. class) then,
>
> $\rho(z)$ is a scalar matrix, ie $\rho(z)=\begin{pmatrix}\omega & 0 & \dots & 0 \\ 0 & \omega & \dots & 0 \\ \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots \\ 0 & 0 & \dots & \omega
>  \end{pmatrix}$
>   where $\omega$ is some root of unity.
>
> **Proof** Say $\omega_1,\dots,\omega_d$ eigenvalues of $\rho(z)$, $d=\dim V = \chi(e)$.
>
> $\chi(C)=\chi(z)=\omega_1+\dots+\omega_d$.
>
> $\frac{\chi(C)}{\chi(e)}=\frac{\omega_1+\dots+\omega_d}{d}:=\alpha$ algebraic integer, $|\alpha| \leq 1$
>
> $\alpha$ root of some (irreducible) polynomial $x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\dots+a_0=0, a_i \in \mathbb{Z}$.
>
> Galois theory $\implies$ all other roots of this polynomial are of the same form.
>
> $$ \frac{\sum \text{ of roots of unity}}{d}$$
>
> which in particular all have absolute value $\leq 1$
>
> Thus all multiply to $a_0 \in \mathbb{Z}, a_0 \neq 0$
>
> $\implies a_0=\pm 1$, all the roots including $\alpha$ have absolute value $=1$.
>
> $\implies|\omega_1+\dots+\omega_d|=d \implies \omega_1=\dots=\omega_d \implies\rho(z)$ scalar.

I cannot see why $\chi(C)=\chi(z)$ nor $\chi(C)=\omega_1+\dots+\omega_d$.

Nor do I understand why $|\alpha| \leq 1$.

Then I cannot understand why "$\implies a_0=\pm 1$, all the roots including $\alpha$ have absolute value $=1$."

Comment: Please dont downvote without commenting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, characters are constant on conjugacy classes, which explains $\chi(C) = \chi(z)$. The eigenvalues of $\rho(z)$ consist of roots of unity, so that the trace of its matrix is a sum $\omega_1 + \cdots + \omega_d$ of roots of unity. It follows that $\frac{\omega_1 + \cdots + \omega_d}{d}$ has norm at most $1$.

Next, the irreducible polynomial has constant term $a_0$, which is simply the product of all the roots. Since $a_0\ne 0$ (otherwise the polynomial is not irreducible) and each root has magnitude at most $1$, we must have $a_0 = \pm 1$ so that the magnitude of each root must be $1$. This implies that $|\omega_1 + \cdots + \omega_d| = d$ so that all the $\omega_i$ must be equal.

Comment: How does it prove that all the $\omega_i$ are equal?

Comment: In general, the triangle inequality shows that $|x+y| \le |x|+|y|$. Equality occurs if and only if $x = \alpha y$ for some constant $\alpha>0$. Since each $\omega_i$ has magnitude $1$, they must be equal.